# In IE9+, How to render iFrame in different document type from parent without inheriting

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-9

My Parent document loads in Quirks Mode. How can i force my iFrame to render in Document Mode IE9?

Comment: I don't think you can. How would that work, exactly? Make newer DOM methods only work over part of the document tree? Changed DOM methods would have to behave different depending on where they were called and their context. It would be a minefield.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes its not possible, they have stopped from IE9+. Realized it.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible, they have stopped from IE9+. Realized it